# Paypal recurring - how to get last transaction detail

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing

How can i get last Paypal transaction details using any of subscription or payer-id in php. I am using Paypal recurring. 
I have to check user's last transaction and on the base of that i have to decide weather user is premium or basic.